# Add node to SQL Server cluster with different OS

Tags: cluster-computing, sql-server-2016, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2019

Can I add a node to a SQL Server cluster that has a different OS than the other node(s)?

Comment: What Operating systems do you want to use? What DBMS?

Comment: It's for SQL Server 2016.  Currently it's on a couple of Windows Server 2012R2 nodes, but we want to use Windows 2019.  Instead of creating a whole new cluster I was hoping to add new nodes (with server 2019) to the current cluster.